# Convert shell script to one liner by escaping necessary thing?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

How to convert a shell script in one-liner by escaping everything? For example: replace end of lines by \n and double the other backslashes and other necessary things.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=$hostname
DATA=""
RETRY=50

echo $HOSTNAME

sleep 1m

while true; do

while [ $RETRY -gt 0 ]
do
    DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/process)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        break
    else
        if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ;
        then
            echo "Server is already running"
        else
            echo "Server is not running so starting it"
            /opt/abc/hello start
        fi
        let RETRY-=1
        sleep 30
    fi
done

if [ $RETRY -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Server is still down. Exiting out of shell script." >&2
    exit 2
fi

echo "Server is up. Now parsing the process."
#grep $DATA for state
state=$(grep -oP 'state: \K\S+' <<< "$DATA")
[[ -z "$state" ]] && state=0

echo "$state"

#validate the conditions
if [[ "$state" == "DONE" || "$state" == "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi

#wait another 30 seconds
sleep 30

done
```

Is there any way to convert above script in one-liner either using Python or Linux by escaping all the necessary things?

Comment: Why would you want that? Each newline can be replaced with a semicolon and that's it.

Comment: `;` is not allowed after `do`, `then` and `else`.

Comment: @Cyrus Right, thanks for the clarification. Updated my answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want that? Each newline can be replaced with a semicolon and that's basically it. After `do`, `then`, and `else`, don't add a semicolon (thanks @Cyrus for pointing this out!) You'll need to remove comments, too.

`hostname` is referenced but never declared. http://shellcheck.net/ gives 5 warnings, though most of them are fairly benign. The `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` antipattern is a pet peeve of mine which I'd very much like to see fixed.

Also, the indentation is broken, though of course that will not matter if you really think you need this to be a one-liner.

If (as in [your deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760230/convert-shell-script-into-one-line-by-escaping-everything-properly)) you want to embed this in a Python script, there is no need to replace the newlines with anything else. Python can accept a string with newlines in it simply by `'''triple-quoting it'''` (though you'll want a `r'''raw string'''` to avoid having Python interpret and replace the backslashes).

```
script=r'''#!/bin/bash

DATA=""
RETRY=50

# avoid copying the variable; quote the string
echo "$hostname"

sleep 1m

while true; do
    # fix indentation    
    while [ $RETRY -gt 0 ]
    do
        # avoid useless use of if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        # quote URL for mainly stylistic reasons
        if DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 "http://$hostname:8080/process")
        then
            break
        else
            if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ;
            then
                # Consistently use stderr for diagnostic messages
                echo "Server is already running" >&2
            else
                echo "Server is not running so starting it" >&2
                /opt/abc/hello start
            fi
            let RETRY-=1
            sleep 30
        fi
    done

    if [ $RETRY -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Server is still down. Exiting out of shell script." >&2
        exit 2
    fi

    # stderr again
    echo "Server is up. Now parsing the process." >&2
    state=$(grep -oP 'state: \K\S+' <<< "$DATA")
    # use a default
    state=${state:-0}
    echo "$state"

    if [[ "$state" == "DONE" || "$state" == "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi

    sleep 30
done'''
```

Here's with semicolons.  Abridged, as I'm sure you get the idea.

```
DATA=""; RETRY=50; echo "$hostname"; sleep 1m; while true; do \
while [ $RETRY -gt 0 ]; do if DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 "http://$hostname:8080/process"); then break; ...
```